# Android : why PhoneCallListener still alive after activity finish?

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

im using a phone call listener in my activity but after finishing my activity , afer user make a call, my phone call listener not dead and brig up activity again !! please help me.

```
phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
            TransferActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

PhoneCallListener class :

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            if (isPhoneCalling) {
                isPhoneCalling = false;
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
                    startActivity(intent);
     Why are you calling above code??

Comment: Unregister your listener in your `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says:

> To un-register a listener, pass the listener object and set the events
>   argument to PhoneStateListener#LISTEN_NONE (0)

Here is the link to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29).

Answer (score 6):

Did you try setting the Listener to null as,

```
telephonyManager.listen(null,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

You need to pass in the same listener you register