# Android : how to stop listening a PhoneCallListener?

Tags: java, android, call, phone-state-listener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : why PhoneCallListener still alive after activity finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666853/android-why-phonecalllistener-still-alive-after-activity-finish)

i'm making a call and using a phone call listener to restart activity when phone state back to IDLE . but after i finish the activity , phone call listener still running, therefore when user make own call and hang-up , my activity bring up again !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LISTEN_NONE` as parameter to `listen` method to stop listening for updates.