# PhoneStateListener will not release and no previously posted answers have worked

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

This question has been asked multiple times before and not a single answer from any of them have solved the problem for me. I have tried every method I could find to unregister my listener by pressing a button, going into onPause, and onDestroy; but the listener persists even when the app is closed. What's more is that I am Toasting the size of an array that my listener is populating, even when the app is closed the Toast remains and continues to increment. I have tried using null and LISTEN_NONE and everything else I could find on the web.

```
// Name of this file is Second.class
public class Second extends Activity {

    SignalStrengthListener signalStrengthListener;
    TextView lteRsrp;
    TextView lteRsrq;
    TextView cellPciTextView;
    TextView timerValue;
    Button startButton, stopButton;

    TelephonyManager tm;
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList;
    String lte1, lte2;
    int cellPci = 0;
    long startTime = 0L;
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    ArrayList<String> rsrpArray;
    ArrayList<String> rsrqArray;
    ArrayList<String> pciArray;


    Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        flag = false;

        rsrpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        rsrqArray = new ArrayList<>();
        pciArray = new ArrayList<>();

        lteRsrp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrp);
        lteRsrq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrq);
        cellPciTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellPciTextView);
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);



        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

                //start the signal strength listener
                signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();

                ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
                tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                try {
                    cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 1: " + e);

                }


                try {
                    for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                        if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                            // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                            // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                            cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("SignalStrength", "++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 2: " + e);
                }

            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                flag = true;

                try{
                    if(signalStrengthListener != null) {
                        tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                        Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Success!!!!!!");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Fail!!!!!! with error = " + e);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };


    private class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

            ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String ltestr = signalStrength.toString();
            String[] parts = ltestr.split(" ");
            lte1 = parts[9];
            lte2 = parts[10];

            try {
                cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
                for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                        // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                        // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                        cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
            }

            if (!flag) {
                rsrpArray.add(lte1);
                rsrqArray.add(lte2);
                pciArray.add(Integer.toString(cellPci));
                int size = rsrpArray.size();
                Toast.makeText(Second.this, "Array size = " + size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            lteRsrp.setText(String.valueOf(lte1));
            lteRsrq.setText(String.valueOf(lte2));
            cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));

            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d("onPause SigStr", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ onPause");
        try{
            if(signalStrengthListener != null){
                tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Success!!!!!!");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Fail!!!!!! with error = " + e);
        }
        flag = true;
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d("onPause SigStr", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ onDestroy");
        try{
            if(signalStrengthListener != null) {
                tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Success!!!!!!");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Fail!!!!!! with error = " + e);
        }
        flag = true;
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

My code is starting to get ugly and redundant as I keep rearranging things in the hope that it might unregister my listener. Following is my XML layout for Second.class. The name of the XML layout file is second_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#42abc0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRP"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRQ"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrq" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE PCI"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timerVal"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And following is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parksjg.its.pscrindoortesttool" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".First"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Again, this question has been asked before BUT none of the posted answers worked!!! Here are a few, and note that none of the answers were up-voted or it was never marked as having worked:
[Android : why PhoneCallListener still alive after activity finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666853/android-why-phonecalllistener-still-alive-after-activity-finish)

[Android : how to stop listening a PhoneCallListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667209/android-how-to-stop-listening-a-phonecalllistener)

Hopefully I am overlooking something simple that someone can point out. Let me know if you need more code or would like me to post the whole Android Studio project on GitHub.

Thank you!!!

Comment: I haven't tested yet but all i can suggest you create global static bool variable and mark it true when application runs such as in onCreate() and mark to false under ondestroy or onpause. And in your listener put condition if(IsApplicationRunning) { //do rest of the stuff } else {//ignore it } this way even if your applicatioh hook up with system despite of not in use then atleast it will look for this condition to run.

Comment: That is what I have been trying lately but no success. If you look in the code above there is the `boolean flag` and I have tried putting it in many different places. For example, in the code above I set the flag to true in the onPause method which should prevent the listener from continuing to execute but it just keeps going. I also wrapped all the code in the SignalStrengthListener in an if-statement using the `flag` bool.

Comment: I also have the debugging comments in the onPause and onDestroy that always print the success comment so I know the listener is getting set to LISTEN_NONE before the 'flag' bool gets reassigned. If you see a more logical way for me to use the `flag` boolean please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was happening. I put some more Log.d() statements in the code to determine how many times the SignalStrengthListener was called. I ran the app for 3 seconds and found the SignalStrengthListener was called approximately 300 times! A lot more than I thought. Now the problem is that Toast can't keep up with how many times it was called; so when I stop or close the app the Toasts continue to appear for several minutes after. My fault was not giving it enough time for the Toasts to catch up before uninstalling the app, at the time I thought that was the only way to stop the listener.

To test this I ran the app again for 3 seconds and got 273 calls to SignalStrengthListener, and every time it is called it makes a Toast. I stopped and closed the app and the Toasts continued to appear for several minutes. However, they finally stopped at the 273 Toast.

Long story short, Toast is not suitable to be called many times a second. This is my fault for not understanding how my listener was operating. In the end, the booleans that I set and the LISTEN_NONE tag to my listener successfully unregistered the listener.

Comment: Please let me know if I should delete my question.